# Javascript - converting local time to google friendly UTC time

Tags: javascript

I want to get the date and time from 2 text boxes and format them and send them to the Google directions javascript API to get transit directions.

How do I add the date and time values together and then convert them to standard UTC time?
This is what i have:

```
var dateOfTravel = document.getElementById('fdate').value; 
var timeOfTravel= document.getElementById('ftime').value; 


//join the date and time strings
var d1 = new Date(dateOfTravel + ' ' + timeOfTravel);
alert("date and time is " + d1);
alert(d1.getTime());

var UTCDateAndTime = moment(d1).unix();
alert(UTCDateAndTime);
```

thanks,
Tom

Comment: Try combinate date and time into one string and parse it into Date object. Then you can work with it as normal javascript Date object.

Comment: What are you getting from alert() call? Where's your HTML? What are you trying to achieve..... specifically?

Comment: I want to send a unix timestamp to google directions. This is what I have so far. I'm getting the date mon oct 25 1915 for the dateOfTravel and 'invalid date' for the time value. This is what I have:

    var dateOfTravel = document.getElementById('fdate').value; 
    var timeOfTravel= document.getElementById('ftime').value; 


    var d1 = new Date(timeOfTravel);
    var     d2 = new Date (dateOfTravel);
    alert(d2);

    //add the time onto the date
    d2.setHours ( d1.getMinutes());
    d2.setMinutes ( d1.getMinutes());

    //set to unix time
    d2.GetTime(); 
    alert(d2);

Comment: What does time have to do with getting directions?

Comment: It's for transit directions. you can set the date and time for when you are departing or arriving.

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- JavaScript dates have `toISOString`, which provides a standard ISO-8601 date/time string always in UTC, e.g. `"2015-10-25T11:02:23.019Z"`. (Yes, the timezone specifier is always `Z`, that's required by the spec. So it doesn't vary by locale or timezone.)
- You can use the various `getUTCXyz` methods to build your own string.
- `getTime` returns the number of milliseconds since The Epoch (Jan 1 1970 at midnight UTC), which is not timezone-dependent.
- `getTimezoneOffset` tells you how far offset you are from UTC, which you could use to adjust things (though I can't see a good reason for that in this case).

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be working:

```
var d1 = new Date(dateOfTravel + ' ' + timeOfTravel);
//if the year is less than 1970 then add 100 on. Using 2 digit years and there's a bug with javascript date implimentation
if (d1.getFullYear() < 1970) {
d1.setFullYear(d1.getFullYear() + 100);
}
```